# Highcharts - xAxis date

Tags: jquery, csv, highcharts

I'm trying to set my xAxis to display a month for every bit of data I input..

so 1, 2, 3, 4 will display as Jan on xAxis and 1 in the yAxis. Feb xAxis and 2 yAxis etc.

*For every bit of data, + a certain amount of time to xAxis and plot.

// I'm doing this from a csv file but if I can get it done from manual input first thats fine.

Any ideas or documentation/examples you could point me to?

Thanks

Comment: See related article: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is doable. See the API for the [xAxis.type](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type) then look at the demo link for `"datetime" with regular intervals`. This provides the basic framework. You tell it the start time ([`pointStart`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointStart)) and what the increments ([`pointInterval`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointInterval)) are going to be for each point.